# T-SQL statement for selecting all records on a future date

Tags: sql-server, date

I need to select all records with a billing date 15 days from now.
This gives me nothing because it is trying to compare date and time:

```
 "nextbill = dateadd(d, +15, getdate())"
```

This works:

```
"select * 
from custrate 
where nextbill >= '2014-01-02 00:00:00' and nextbill < '2014-01-02 23:59:59'"
```

How do I get everything with a date of 15 days from now ignoring the time?

Comment: Note - 2014-01-02 is _16_ days from today (2013-12-17)

Comment: FYI, the SQL dialect used by SQL Server is "T-SQL" (or "Transact SQL").

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select * 
from custrate 
where convert(date,nextbill) = DATEADD(d, 15, convert(date,getdate()))
```

or older versions of sql:

```
select * 
from custrate 
where DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, nextbill), 0) = DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 15)
```

Comment: you must be on an older version; solution added for older versions

Comment: see second query in my answer then

Comment: Ugh. Both of these queries are bad news. While the first one will be able to use an index, this is just a coincidence - in most cases you don't ever want to apply a function to the column side of an expression. In this case [there is a bad side effect as well](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea). The second one violates this practice in a huge way - this will cause a scan even when a seek could have been used. ([Also may be subject to this bug](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/datediff-bug)).

Answer (score 7):

I would use the start of the day with `>=` and start of the next day with a `<`...

```
declare @from datetime, @thru datetime;
set @from = dateadd(d, datediff(d, 0, getdate()) + 15, 0);
set @thru = dateadd(d, 1, @from);

select ...
from custrate
where nextbill >= @from and nextbill < @thru
```

Comment: This will get the data for two days.

Comment: +1 an open-ended range is absolutely the most efficient and safest method to retrieve all of the data for a day (or range).

Comment: Efficiency point taken.  Why is an open-ended range the "safest"?  Is the selected answer "unsafe"?

Comment: The selected answer isn't unsafe, just guaranteed to perform as poorly as any solution. The open-ended range is safest OMHO because it is not sensitive to underlying data type changes. A lot of people will between start and dateadd(millisecond,-3,end) and this is terrifyingly unsafe.

Comment: @user210757 see [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates)

Comment: How would you recommend doing this with the +1 method ?

Comment: I think I figured it out:  select * from custrate where (nextbill >= DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 15)) and (nextbill < DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 16))